# Database modelled with ArrayList vs SQL in terms of efficiency

Tags: android, performance

I'm developing an android app that uses various Lists of Java Modelled entities and `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream` to store and load these.

The average complexity of my dataManager is `4*O(n^3)` for update all entries of 4 different data sets at the same time, where every operation requires 3 nested `for` on an `ArrayList` because an Object `Palace` contains a List of `Apartament` and an Object `Apartament` contains a list of `People`

Could I have noticeable slow down in the app due to my approach?

what is the efficience If I use SQLite to perform the same operations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion SQL would offer some advantages.

In terms of efficiency, I can't tell you which one is better (file vs database) without discussing the amount of data you're holding. 2 or 3 records is a very different story than 10,000 records (without even considering the nested levels).

If you're using a file, you have to load everything manually into memory to access your objects, and this means (most of the time) loading the file completely, and saving it completely again.

A database would allow you to fetch only the information that you currently need, and it also allows you to only save the data that has been modified.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. consider a large number of records. what about efficiency of SqLite in geting each records to update this and resave in the db the new value?

Comment: If you're always going to update ALL your data, a plain file is faster, because the DB has a lot of overhead (parsing SQL statements, searching, indexing, sorting...).